# Xcode, Swift: how to add multi-language support in an iOS app and have strings with placeholders and plurals?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, localization, pluralize

I need to add multi-language support in an iOS app that is written in Xcode using Swift. I need to localize

1. Static strings
2. Strings with placeholders
3. plurals (quantity-strings)

Such as below in Android we add named strings and plurals in XML files:

```xml
<string name="static_string">Hello world!</string>
<string name="placeholder_string">You have %2$d new messages.</string>
<plurals name="plural_string">
    <item quantity="one">You have a new message.</item>
    <item quantity="other">You have %2$d new messages.</item>
</plurals>
```

And following Java to get strings programmatically:

```
res.getString(R.string.placeholder_string, mailCount)
res.getQuantityString(R.plurals.plural_string, mailCount, mailCount)
```

I am looking for the solution corresponding to Swift (iOS)

Comment: SO rarely converts code for free, give it a try yourself and if you run into problems we'll be here to help.

Comment: "Plural Rule Properties" in the Apple documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/StringsdictFileFormat/StringsdictFileFormat.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171i-CH16-SW4.

Comment: What if the placeholder is another string instead of the the plural counter?
I asked that question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39180444/how-to-add-a-regular-string-placeholders-to-a-translated-plurals-stringdict-in

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Setup project `Localizations`, as shown in screenshot the project has English and Russian languages.

[image]

1: Create a file named `Localizable.strings` and add following lines

```
static_string="Hello world!";
placeholder_string="You have %d new messages.";
```

2: We define Plurals in a separate file, lets create a file named `Localizable.stringsdict` and paste following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">

<!-- FIRST PLURAL STRING -->
<dict>
    <key>plural_string</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSStringLocalizedFormatKey</key>
        <string>%#@value@</string>
        <key>value</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSStringFormatSpecTypeKey</key>
            <string>NSStringPluralRuleType</string>
            <key>NSStringFormatValueTypeKey</key>
            <string>d</string>
            <key>one</key>
            <string>You have a new message.</string>
            <key>other</key>
            <string>You have %d new messages.</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>

<!-- NEXT PLURAL STRING -->
</plist>
```

Next, localize `Localizable.stringsdict` file, see in screenshot, the file is localized for English and Russian languages:

[image]

Usage:

```
NSLocalizedString("static_string", comment: "") // Hello world!

String(format: NSLocalizedString("placeholder_string", comment: ""), 5) // You have 5 new messages.

let plural = NSLocalizedString("plural_string", comment: "")
String(format: plural, 1) // You have a new message.
String(format: plural, 2) // You have 2 new messages.
```

**Plural Rules:** In XML code, notice `<key>one</key>` and `<key>other</key>`, here you can use `zero`, `one`, `two`, `few`, `many`, `other` depending on the language and your requirements.

Use following link for more information on language specific plural rules: http://www.unicode.org/cldr/charts/latest/supplemental/language_plural_rules.html

Also this article will help if you are new to string formatting https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html

Answer (score 5):

[This blog explains](http://crunchybagel.com/localizing-plurals-in-ios-development/) in great detail what plurals are all about. with code examples for IOS.

> in some languages, plurals don't work the same way as they do in
>   English. Some languages don't indicate plurals (such as Japanese),
>   while for others the word will change depending on the quantity (such
>   as Russian).
>
> To make things a bit easier, iOS has categorised the different plural
>   types as follows:
>
> - Zero. Used to indicate a 0 quantity.
> - One. Used to indicate a    quantity of exactly 1.
> - Two. Used to indicate a quantity of exactly 2.
> - Few. Used to indicate a small quantity greater than 2, but this depends on the language.
> - Many. Used to indicate a large number, but    this also depends on the language.
>
> Other. Used to indicate every number that isn't covered by the above
>   categories.
>
> Not all languages need all categories
>   specified, since all work differently. At first glance, it would
>   appear that English would require rules for zero, one and many.
>   However, the plural rules for English would be specified with one and
>   other, since all numbers apart from 1 are treated equally.
>
> To specify the plural rules, you need to use a strings dictionary
>   (Localizable.stringsdict) instead of a regular Localizable.strings
>   file. In actual fact, you'll need the .strings file to still be
>   present for the .stringsdict to work, even if it's empty.
>
> In Xcode, create a new Plist file, and name it
>   Localizable.stringsdict. Once populated, the raw data in the Plist
>   will look as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
    <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">  
    <plist version="1.0">  
    <dict>  
        <key>number_of_days</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSStringLocalizedFormatKey</key>
            <string>%#@value@</string>
            <key>value</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSStringFormatSpecTypeKey</key>
                <string>NSStringPluralRuleType</string>
                <key>NSStringFormatValueTypeKey</key>
                <string>d</string>
                <key>one</key>
                <string>%d day remaining</string>
                <key>other</key>
                <string>%d days remaining</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>  
    </plist>
```

And this is how to reference the plural in code:

```
let format = NSLocalizedString("number_of_days", comment: "")
let message = String.localizedStringWithFormat(format, numDays)
```

Again, credit goes to [Quentin](http://crunchybagel.com/author/quentin/)