# How to add regular string placeholders to a translated plurals .stringdict in swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, translation, plural

I want to translate this string using a plurar stringdict in swift for iOS

- stays at %1$@
- stay at %1$@

Using a simple plural without placeholders works, thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30207436/dynamic-strings-with-placeholders-and-plural-support-in-swift-ios/39105219#39105219)
But when I add a string placeholder I get a crash when accessing it.

The **regular plurals are working** using the following xml:

```
<dict>
<key>NSStringLocalizedFormatKey</key>
<string>%#@format@</string>
<key>format</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSStringFormatSpecTypeKey</key>
    <string>NSStringPluralRuleType</string>
    <key>NSStringFormatValueTypeKey</key>
    <string>li</string>
    <key>one</key>
    <string>Sleeps at your place</string>
    <key>other</key>
    <string>Sleep at your place</string>
</dict>
</dict>
```

And using this swift code to reference the plural above without string placeholder:

```
 let format = NSLocalizedString("key_to_plural_above", comment: "")
 let label = String.localizedStringWithFormat(format, kidsIds.count)
```

The problem is **when I add a string placeholder to the translation I get a crash** when I try to read it. The xml below is generated by a translation tool ([lokalise](https://lokalise.co/)) so I assume it's correct.

```
<dict>
<key>NSStringLocalizedFormatKey</key>
<string>%#@format@</string>
<key>format</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSStringFormatSpecTypeKey</key>
    <string>NSStringPluralRuleType</string>
    <key>NSStringFormatValueTypeKey</key>
    <string>li</string>
    <key>one</key>
    <string>Sleeps at %1$@</string>
    <key>other</key>
    <string>Sleep at %1$@</string>
</dict>
```

**Using this swift code to get the plural above, I get an unknown crash without any stacktrace:**

```
let format = NSLocalizedString("key_to_plural_above", comment: "")
let label = String.localizedStringWithFormat(format, kidsIds.count, "Name")
```

Comment: can you tell me does lokalise slow down your app start time ? how does the synching work ? is it real time ?

Comment: For details about the lokalise services ask the company. This question is not about lokalise. I also don't know the answers to your questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Positional parameters `n$` are one-based, so in

```
let label = String.localizedStringWithFormat(format, kidsIds.count, "Name")
```

`"Name"` is the second parameter, and you reference it with `%2$@`:

```
<key>NSStringLocalizedFormatKey</key>
<string>%#@format@</string>
<key>format</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSStringFormatSpecTypeKey</key>
    <string>NSStringPluralRuleType</string>
    <key>NSStringFormatValueTypeKey</key>
    <string>li</string>
    <key>one</key>
    <string>Sleeps at %2$@</string>
    <key>other</key>
    <string>Sleep at %2$@</string>
</dict>
```

In your code, `%1$@` refers to the first argument `kidsIds.count`.
That is not a string which leads to the crash.

Alternatively, put it into the NSStringLocalizedFormatKey:

```
<key>NSStringLocalizedFormatKey</key>
<string>%#@format@ at %@</string>
<key>format</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSStringFormatSpecTypeKey</key>
    <string>NSStringPluralRuleType</string>
    <key>NSStringFormatValueTypeKey</key>
    <string>li</string>
    <key>one</key>
    <string>Sleeps</string>
    <key>other</key>
    <string>Sleep</string>
</dict>
```

Comment: Thanks! On android the plural-number is not counted as placeholer, thus the confusion. This solution will lead to Android code passing null as the first placeholder..not ideal but working!

Comment: I am not sure if I ask it correctly. In this case to which parameter would pluralization apply? How does `String` determine which parameter to use the first or the second to choose `one` or `other` variant?

Comment: @iur: The `%#@format@` placeholder uses the dictionary defined with `<key>format</key>` – “format” is an arbitrary string here.