# iOS. Pluralization. Stringdict with format that contains 2 int arguments

Tags: ios, swift, translation, plural

My question is similar to [How to add regular string placeholders to a translated plurals .stringdict in swift ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39180444/how-to-add-regular-string-placeholders-to-a-translated-plurals-stringdict-in-sw) but I am trying to understand if it is possible to pass 2 int parameters to strings dict.

Say if I want to translate something like:

```
1 apple : 3 pears
2 apples : 1 pear
```

Is it possible to do it in one localized format string like:

```
let apples = 1
let pears = 3
let applesAndPears = String.localizedStringWithFormat(<format>, apples, pears)
print(applesAndPears)
```

or do I have to combine them separately?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One format is sufficient. You can use multiple placeholders in the `NSStringLocalizedFormatKey` entry, and for each placeholder a separate dictionary with the plural rule. Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>apples_and_pears</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSStringLocalizedFormatKey</key>
            <string>%#@num_apples@ : %#@num_pears@</string>
            <key>num_apples</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSStringFormatSpecTypeKey</key>
                <string>NSStringPluralRuleType</string>
                <key>NSStringFormatValueTypeKey</key>
                <string>ld</string>
                <key>zero</key>
                <string>no apple</string>
                <key>one</key>
                <string>1 apple</string>
                <key>other</key>
                <string>%ld apples</string>
            </dict>
            <key>num_pears</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSStringFormatSpecTypeKey</key>
                <string>NSStringPluralRuleType</string>
                <key>NSStringFormatValueTypeKey</key>
                <string>ld</string>
                <key>zero</key>
                <string>no pear</string>
                <key>one</key>
                <string>1 pear</string>
                <key>other</key>
                <string>%ld pears</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

Usage:

```
let apples = 1
let pears = 3
let format = NSLocalizedString("apples_and_pears", comment: "")
let applesAndPears = String.localizedStringWithFormat(format, apples, pears)
print(applesAndPears) // 1 apple : 3 pears
```

This can be combined with positional parameters: if the format is changed to

```
        <key>NSStringLocalizedFormatKey</key>
        <string>%2$#@num_pears@ : %1$#@num_apples@</string>
```

then the output becomes “3 pears : 1 apple”.

Comment: Can I also use `$1`, `$2`, `...` to be able to swap parameters places for other languages if necessary? How would that look like? Or do I need to swap formats in that case? `EN: %#@num_apples@ : %#@num_pears@` -> `FR: %#@num_pears@ : %#@num_apples@`