# Multiple plurals in a single localized string

Tags: ios, swift, localization

Is it possible to use the `.stringsdict` format to handle multiple plurals in a single localized string? For example:

> `You have %1$d apples and %1$d oranges`

I guess I would need to somehow provide all permutations of plural forms in each language, so in English there are four:

> `You have %1$d apple and %1$d orange`
>
> `You have %1$d apple and %1$d oranges`
>
> `You have %1$d apples and %1$d orange`
>
> `You have %1$d apples and %1$d oranges`

But I can't figure out if this is even possible, let alone how to specify it.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for [iOS. Pluralization. Stringdict with format that contains 2 int arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55752969/ios-pluralization-stringdict-with-format-that-contains-2-int-arguments) ?

Comment: Yes - thanks @MartinR